# Filter being too aggressive

Tags: clojure, macros

I have tried to make it unnecessary to fully understand the code, so read the whole question first, then dig into the code if necessary.

I'm trying to make a macro for pattern matching.
It works by taking a list in which the first element is type of matching to be performed

Example: the first element in the list is "cons"; the macro would call a cons matching function.

A matching function takes an object and a function, calls the function with the matched value.  With the cons matcher, it would call the function with the head and tail of the list.

I used a "num" matcher for testing.  It's basically an identity matcher, so it could be nested inside itself arbitrarily, as I did below.

```
;a macro to make debugging easier
(defmacro log [item] `(do (print ~(join [(str item) ": "])) (println ~item)))

(defn make-pattern-matcher-iter [result bindings-queue]
  (println "starting next iteration")
  (log bindings-queue)
  (if (first bindings-queue) (println "bindings-queue does contain an element") nil)
  (if (first bindings-queue)
    (let [[next-symbol pattern] (first bindings-queue)
          pattern-name (first pattern)
          pattern-items (next pattern)
          pattern-matching-function (prepend-symbol "match-" pattern-name)
          gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns (map (fn [pattern]
                                                (if (symbol? pattern)
                                                  pattern
                                                  `(~(gensym "matchbinding") ~pattern)))
                                              pattern-items)
          all-bound-symbols (map (fn [sym]
                                  (if (symbol? sym) sym (first sym)))
                                gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns)
          gensyms-subpattern-pairs (filter list? gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns)
          rest-of-bindings-queue (next bindings-queue)
          updated-bindings-queue (concat rest-of-bindings-queue 
                                        gensyms-subpattern-pairs)
          subpatterns (map second gensyms-subpattern-pairs)]
      (log next-symbol)
      (log all-bound-symbols)
      (log updated-bindings-queue)
      (log gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns)
      (log gensyms-subpattern-pairs)
      (log subpatterns)
      `(~pattern-matching-function
        ~next-symbol 
        (fn [~@all-bound-symbols] ~(make-pattern-matcher-iter result updated-bindings-queue))))
    result))

(defn make-pattern-matcher [object pattern result] (make-pattern-matcher-iter result [[object pattern]]))


(defn match-num [x f]
  (if (number? x) (f x) nil))


(def this-m (make-pattern-matcher-iter '(+ x y) [['object '(pair x y)]]))
(def this-n (make-pattern-matcher '15 '(num (num z)) 'z))
(= this-n this-m)

(defmacro bind-match [object pattern result] (make-pattern-matcher object pattern result))

(bind-match 15 (num (num z)) z)
```

The problem is that the macro isn't properly binding "z"

the log gives on the second iteration:

```
gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns: ((matchbinding8210 (num z)))
gensyms-subpattern-pairs: ()
```

there are other log messages, but these seem to be the problem.

Take a look at how `gensyms-subpattern-pairs` is calculated. In the let block it says:

```
gensyms-subpattern-pairs (filter list? gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns)
```

this should take out everything but lists, which is all there is, so it shouldn't take out anything.
The filter seems to be too aggressive.  Why?

Comment: What does `(map type gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns)` give?

Comment: @Elogent it gives ```(clojure.lang.Cons)```.  Are cons's still lists?

Comment: @Elogent Aha, ```(list? (cons 4 [5]))``` returns false. If you want to give an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the elements of `gensyms-attached-to-subpatterns` are not `IPersistentList`s, but rather `Cons`es. Sanity check:

```
(contains? (supers clojure.lang.Cons) clojure.lang.IPersistentList)
;=> false
```

So it looks like you'll need to use some other check than `list?`.

Comment: Specifically I used ```seq?```